# Non-Linear regression

Tags: regression, estimation

Imagine that I have a function $ f(x,y) $ to model a physical phenomenon.

I believe that functions is defined by $$ f(x,y) = A*x + B*y + C*x*y$$

I have many values for $ (x,y,f(x,y)) $, how can I find the approximated value for $(A,B,C)$?

There are the values:

```
f(x,y)  |   x   |   y
--------+-------+-------
874     |  75   |  7
954     |  75   |  4
2696    |  75   |  30
2731    |  75   |  29
4227    |  343  |  4
4504    |  75   |  4
4714    |  343  |  7
4962    |  75   |  7
6592    |  75   |  29
6718    |  75   |  30
9419    |  343  |  29
9770    |  343  |  30
12982   |  639  |  4
16184   |  639  |  7
19898   |  1389 |  7
24528   |  1389 |  4
29382   |  639  |  29
29638   |  2101 |  4
30095   |  2274 |  7
30297   |  2101 |  7
30876   |  2274 |  4
31856   |  639  |  30
35121   |  1389 |  30
38708   |  1389 |  29
50192   |  3676 |  4
50482   |  3676 |  7
60837   |  2274 |  30
61340   |  2101 |  29
61850   |  2101 |  30
64533   |  2274 |  29
104421  |  3676 |  29
105073  |  3676 |  30
```

Comment: Find a piece of software that does curve-fitting. I know that gnuplot, e.g., can do nonlinear regression.

Comment: I don't want a answer for these values. I want a mathematical answer for this questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like with linear regression: minimize
$$
\sum_i (f(x_i,y_i) - Ax_i - By_i - Cx_iy_i)^2
$$
on $A,B,C$.

Comment: How the best way to calculate the values of A, B and C?

Comment: You have to find the partial derivatives of this sum on $A,B,C$, to equate  the derivatives to zero and to solve the system of equations (just as for the linear regression!)

Comment: I'm trying to solve it, but for all derivatives I found the same equation: $\overline{f}=A*\overline{x}+B*\overline{y}+C*\overline{x}*\overline{y}$. How can I do?

Comment: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial A}\sum_i (f(x_i,y_i) - Ax_i - By_i - Cx_iy_i)^2$$ $$=-2\sum_i x_i(f(x_i,y_i) - Ax_i - By_i - Cx_iy_i)$$  etc.

Comment: The next step I can suppose that $\sum_i x_i=0$ or $\sum_i (f(x_i,y_i) - Ax_i - By_i - Cx_iy_i)=0$. And I get the same resulto for 3 equations. Is that correct?

Comment: No. $$\sum_i x_i(f(x_i,y_i) - Ax_i - By_i - Cx_iy_i)\ne \sum_i x_i\cdot\sum_i(f(x_i,y_i) - Ax_i - By_i - Cx_iy_i)$$

Comment: @Victor, the first equation has a form $$A\sum_i x_i^2 + B\sum_i x_iy_i + C\sum_i x_i^2y_i = \sum_i x_if(x_i,y_i)$$